# Blogger: Como exibir apenas as postagens de um marcador (label) específico na homepage do blog?

Tags: html, blogger

Estou enfrentando sérias dificuldades em solucionar um problema na criação de um template que deveria ser simples de resolver, mas já está me consumindo muito tempo sem chegar a uma solução.

Ocorre que criei um template XHTML Strict do zero, para usar em um blog com dois DIVs padrões (id="div-1" e id="div-2") em forma de duas colunas que ocupam, cada uma, 50% da tela.

Na `<b:section>` principal da homepage, que está dentro do "div-1", são exibidas normalmente todas as postagens publicadas, das mais recentes para as mais antigas. Para isto, usei o seguinte código:

```
<div id="div-1">
<b:section id='main'>
    <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Todas as postagens' type='Blog'>
    </b:widget>
</b:section>
<div>
```

Até aí tudo bem.
Acontece que no "div-2", eu quero que sejam exibidas SOMENTE as postagens com um marcador **específico**, neste caso "Notícias".

Para isso tentei usar o seguinte código:

```
<div id="div-2">
<b:section id='noticias'>
<b:widget id='Blog2' locked='true' title='Notícias' type='Blog'>

  <b:includable id='main2'>
    <b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;Notícias&quot;'>
    <data:content/>
    </b:if>
  </b:includable>

</b:widget>
</b:section>
<div>
```

O código acima até exibe as postagens, mas de forma igual ao "div-1".
Mesmo revisando o código não consigo visualizar onde está o erro que impede das postagens serem exibidas APENAS com o marcador "Notícias".

Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda, pois só falta isto para eu acabar o blog e já estou há dias tentando resolver isto, sem sucesso.

Comment: _Blogger_ não é uma linguagem de programação, mas sim uma terminologia referente à site de discussão ou informação [«1»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blogger_%28service%29) [«2»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blog), e são normalmente desenvolvidos utilizando várias linguagens web, não uma. Assim sendo, bom seria, se desta vez editasses a tua pergunta, não ignorando o título imposto, mas mudando algum ou mesmo todo conteúdo referente a _blogger language_. Porque assim as pessoas não te conseguem acompanhar.

Comment: Oi Edilson, obrigado pela observação. Eu quis formular a pergunta da forma mais específica possível, mas acabei errando a classificação da mesma como "blogger language". Na verdade, tentei me referir às "Tags de Elementos da Página" do Blogger, conforme descreve esta página: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46888?hl=pt-BR&ref_topic=12449 . Alterei o título, deixando apenas a referência ao nome do serviço (Blogger), pois se não a pergunta pode ficar ambígua em relação a outros serviços de blog (WordPress, WebNode, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui achar a solução!

O código do "div-2" deve ter algumas sequências condicionais de tags `<b:loop>` que servirão para exibir as postagens filtradas de acordo com o marcador (label) que você deseja.

Como exposto na própria pergunta, o código para exibir todas as postagens de forma normal deve ser:

**DIV-1 (Todas as postagens)**

```
<div id="div-1">
<b:section id='main'>
    <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Todas as postagens' type='Blog'>
    </b:widget>
</b:section>
<div>
```

Já no "div-2", para não haver conflito com o primeiro div, deve ser usado o código abaixo:

**DIV-2 (Somente postagens com o marcador "NOTÍCIAS")**

```
<div id="div-2">
    <b:section id='posts-noticias'>
    <b:widget id='Blog2' locked='true' title='Blog Archive' type='Blog'>

    <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
        <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
        <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.name == "NOTÍCIAS"'>
        <b:include data='post' name='printPosts'/>
        </b:if>
        </b:loop>
        </b:if>
        <b:else/>
        <b:include data='post' name='printPosts'/>
        </b:if>
        </b:loop>
    </b:includable>

    <b:includable id='printPosts' var='post'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
        <h2 class='date-header'>
        <data:post.dateHeader/>
        </h2>
        </b:if>
        <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
        <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
        <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
        </b:if>
    </b:includable>

</b:widget>
</b:section>
```

Caso deseje incluir algum marcador personalizado do seu blog, basta substituir a palavra "NOTÍCIAS" no código acima pela palavra que preferir.

Assim, será possível exibir na mesma página da homepage uma seção com as postagens normais e outra com as postagens filtradas por uma determinada categoria.

Espero que esta pequena resposta consiga ajudar outras pessoas que estejam com o mesmo problema.

Obrigado. De nada!